# Cucumber - perform the direct call to the api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, thor

I have the thor task, which launches failing tests. I don't like my current approach, so I decided to use direct call to the Cucumber API to perform tests running (it enables highlighting, for example). So, I have such thor task:

**lib/tasks/parallel.thor**

```
require File.expand_path('config/environment.rb')
require 'cucumber/cli/main'

class Parallel < MyProject::TasksBase
  def rerun_with_cucumber
    # ...
    Cucumber::Cli::Main.new(["@tmp/parallel_cucumber_failures_copy.log"]).execute!
  end
end
```

When I try to launch this task I recieve the error:

```
Using the default profile...
@javascript @sphinx
Feature: Edit a service

  Scenario Outline: Editing                                                         # features/service/edit.feature:3
    Given I exist as an "individual"                                                # features/step_definitions/user.steps.rb:18
    ...
    Then I should see I18n translation for key "views.services.titles.edit"         # features/step_definitions/share.steps.rb:129
    And I update form for service and choose price as "<price>"                     # features/step_definitions/service.steps.rb:295
    And I click on I18n translation for key "views.labels.publish"                  # features/step_definitions/share.steps.rb:54
    Then I should see I18n translation for key "views.messages.notices.add.updated" # features/step_definitions/share.steps.rb:129

    Examples: 
      | price      |
      | fixed      |      
      uninitialized constant FactoryGirl (NameError)
      /Users/serj/Projects/my-project/features/support/env.rb:70:in `Before'

      uninitialized constant FactoryGirl (NameError)
      ./features/support/spec_helper.rb:55:in `eval'
      (eval):1:in `create_and_init'
      ./features/support/spec_helper.rb:55:in `eval'
      ./features/support/spec_helper.rb:55:in `create_and_init'
      ./features/step_definitions/user.steps.rb:19:in `/^I exist as [a|an]+ "([^\"]*)"$/'
      features/service/edit.feature:4:in `Given I exist as an "individual"'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/service/edit.feature:3 # Scenario: Editing
```

This test works normally, when I launch it manually with the bash it the terminal. But when I try to run this test from thor task, it fails. How can I fix that?

Comment: do you have `gem factory_girl_rails`

Comment: @RajarshiDas Yes, of course.

Comment: you should be point to spec/factories folder ? for define/register factories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem was that Thor runs in `development` mode by default, not `test`. To solve my problem I just needed to set this ENV variable:

`RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec thor ...`

This helped me. Second hint: make sure in your task, that you are in Test ENV, otherwise you'll lose all your development data. You can check out my [article about this task](http://bloginius.com/blog/2014/05/12/how-thor-can-help-you-with-your-tests-or-integration-of-parallel-tests-and-cucumber/).